# How to use multiple JWT authentication for different tables in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, jwt, token

I got an error while i was making registration and authentication for standard user and admin
when i login to user it is going well and i am getting JWT token by when i am passing data to administrator it is going automatically to user not administrator which means that the when i put standard user data into admin api it is giving me token but for the administrator data in adminstrator api it is not working
please help me

This is the code **Adminstrator.php** model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

class Adminstrator extends Model
{

  protected $guard='adminstrator';
//    protected $table='adminstrator';

  /**
   * The attributes that are mass assignable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $fillable = [
      'username', 'provider_providerName','phone', 'email', 'password', 'description',
  ];



  /**
   * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $hidden = [
      'password', 'remember_token',
  ];

  /**
   * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $casts = [
      'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
  ];



  public function provider(){
      return $this->belongsTo(\App\Provider::class);
  }
}
```

And this is for **user.php** model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

class User extends Model
{


    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The primary key of my table
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guard = 'adminstrator';
    protected $primaryKey = 'username';
    protected $keyType = 'string';


    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username','phone', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];


    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Like::class);
    }
    public function dislikes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Dislike::class);
    }
    public function downloads()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Download::class);
    }
    public function reports()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Report::class);
    }
    public function views()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\View::class);
    }

    public function wishlists(){
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Wishlist::class);
    }

    public function profile(){
        return $this->hasOne(\App\User::class);
    }

    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }

}

namespace App;
```

After this is my **AdminstratorController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Adminstrator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class AdminstratorController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Create a new AuthController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:adminstrator', ['except' => ['login', 'register']]);
    }







    /**
     * Get a JWT token via given credentials.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');
        // dd($credentials);
        // dd($this->guard('adminstrator')->attempt($credentials));
        if ($token = $this->guard()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return $this->respondWithToken($token);
        }

        return response()->json(['error' => 'Wrong Credentials'], 401);
    }




    /**
     * register Admin
     *
     */

    public function register(Request $request)
    {

        $request->validate([
            'username' => 'required |unique:adminstrators|min:10',
            'provider_providerName' => 'unique:adminstrators',
            'email' => 'email|unique:adminstrators',
            'phone' => 'unique:adminstrators',
            'password' => 'required|min:10',
            'c_password' => 'required |same:password',
            'description' => 'required |min:200|string'
        ]);

        // dd($request->all());

        $admin = Adminstrator::create([
            'username' => $request->username,
            'provider_providerName' =>  $request->provider_providerName,
            'phone' => $request->phone,
            'email' =>  $request->email,
            'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
            'description' => $request->description,
        ]);

        $admin->username = $request->username;
        return response($admin);
    }



    /**
     * Get the authenticated User
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function me()
    {
        return response()->json($this->guard()->user());
    }




    /**
     * Log the user out (Invalidate the token)
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully logged out']);
    }






    /**
     * Refresh a token.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */

    public function refresh()
    {
        return $this->respondWithToken($this->guard()->refresh());
    }




    /**
     * Get the token array structure.
     *
     * @param  string $token
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */

    protected function respondWithToken($token)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => $this->guard()->factory()->getTTL() * 60
        ]);
    }






    /**
     * Log the user out (Invalidate the token)
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */





    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during authentication.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard
     */

    public function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard();
    }
    public function payload()
    {

        return auth()->payload();
    }
}
```

And this is my **UserController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\UserNotDefinedException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Create a new AuthController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login','register']]);
    }

    /**
     * Get a JWT token via given credentials.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');

        if ($token = $this->guard()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return $this->respondWithToken($token);
        }

        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    }


    public function register(Request $request){

        $request->validate([
            'username' => 'required |unique:users',
            'phone' => 'unique:users',
            'email' => 'email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required',
            'c_password' => 'required |same:password',
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'username' =>$request->username,
            'phone' =>  $request->phone,
            'email' =>  $request->email,
            'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
        ]);

        $user->username = $request->username;       
        return response($user);

    }


    /**
     * Get the authenticated User
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function me()
    {
        /**
         * Check if user have logen in 
         */
        try {

            if (!$user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) { 
                return response('User not found',404);
            }
        } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {

            return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());
        } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {

            return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());
        } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {

            return response()->json(['token_absent'], $e->getStatusCode());
        }


        return response()->json(compact('user'));

        // return response()->json($this->guard()->user());
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out (Invalidate the token)
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully logged out']);
    }

    /**
     * Refresh a token.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function refresh()
    {
        return $this->respondWithToken($this->guard()->refresh());
    }

    /**
     * Get the token array structure.
     *
     * @param  string $token
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function respondWithToken($token)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => $this->guard()->factory()->getTTL() * 60
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out (Invalidate the token)
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */


    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during authentication.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard
     */
    public function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard();
    }
    public function payload()
    {

        return auth()->payload();
    }
}
```

And this is is my **config/auth.php**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'adminstrator' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'adminstrators',
        ]


    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'adminstrators' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Adminstrator::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
        'adminstrators' => [
            'provider' => 'adminstrators',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```